# Update Plotly chart type from Scatter to Table using Dropdown menus

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to display the table behind a scatter plot using dropdown menus. The problem I am facing is the display of the Table when clicking on Table option, and back to scatter. Both Charts are displayed on top of each other when clicking on Table. Only the first render is done correctly displaying the scatter plot.

[Image of Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MazSE.png)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

values = ['A Scores', 'B Scores']
x = [100, 90, 80, 90]
y = [95, 85, 75, 95]

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x,
                     y=y,
                     mode='markers',
                    ))


fig.add_trace(go.Table(
    header=dict(values=values),
    cells=dict(values=[x,y]),
    visible= False,
))


# Add dropdown
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        dict(
            active=0,
            buttons=list([
                dict(label="Scatter",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [True, False]},
                           {"title": "Scatter"}]),
                dict(label="Table",
                     method="update",
                     args=[{"visible": [False, True]},
                           {"title": "Table"}]),
            ]),
        )
    ])


fig.show()
```

Comment: your approach looks right.  it appears to be a bug.  I'me using plotly 5.1.0, what version are you using?

Comment: [Same issue tracked here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4640), no solution yet it seems.

Comment: RobRaymond: plotly 5.1.0 as well. 
BasvanderLinden: thanks for pointing out to the open issue on plotly.js